# Why do i keep getting a keyerror when assigning the first set of information to data variable to context?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

Keep getting keyerror when trying to append a dictionary to a list in the context variable for get_context_data for django.

```py
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(AdminPlayersView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['form_add'] = self.get_form()
        context['form_edit'] = self.get_form()
        players = Players.objects.all().order_by("user__last_name")
        context['data'] = []
        for player in players:
            info = {
            'Name': player.full_name,
            'DOB': player.user.dob,
            'Gender': player.user.gender,
            'Team': 'Something',
            }
            context['data'].append(info)

        return context
```

This is the error message i get, i've only changed the data in info for privacy reasons.

```
`    __class__  
    <class 'Backend.views.AdminPlayersView'>
    context 
    {'data': {}}
    count   0
    info    {'DOB': '2019-01-01', 'Gender': 1, 'Name': 'Name', 'Team': 
    'Something'}
    kwargs  {}
    player  <Players: Players object (240)>
players 
<QuerySet [<Players: Players object (240)>, <Players: Players object (13)>, <Players: Players object (46)>, <Players: Players object (217)>, <Players: Players object (96)>, <Players: Players object (301)>, <Players: Players object (481)>, <Players: Players object (201)>, <Players: Players object (48)>, <Players: Players object (129)>, <Players: Players object (152)>, <Players: Players object (343)>, <Players: Players object (344)>, <Players: Players object (206)>, <Players: Players object (381)>, <Players: Players object (375)>, <Players: Players object (469)>, <Players: Players object (23)>, <Players: Players object (104)>, <Players: Players object (8)>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
self    
<Backend.views.AdminPlayersView object at 0x078118D0>
```

```
edit:
'Name'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin//players
Django Version: 2.1.1
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'Name'
```

Comment: Can you also add exact text of the exception?

Comment: i did at the bottom?

Comment: where is the line with text `KeyError(): some_key`? It usually mentions the problematic key. And you only mentioned type of exception in question title.

Comment: Just added the only exception text i had from the page

Comment: Do you access `some_obj['Name']` anywhere in your code? maybe you have some `property` attributes on  the `Player` model that use dicts? It's very strange: maybe you are not giving correct code snippet. For example: `context['data']` is a dictionary (`context == {'data': {}}`), so `context['data'].append` should fail with `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why `KeyError`?

In your `for` loop, you are assigning your **`info`** dict to a key called **`data`** which is not a key belongs to the **`context`**.
So, create a **`list`** inside the **`context`** dict as,

```
context['data'] = []
```

and then append to this list.

---

Complete code example

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    context = super().get_serializer_context()
    context['data'] = []
    players = Players.objects.all().order_by("user__last_name")
    for player in players:
        info = {
            'Name': player.full_name,
            'DOB': player.user.dob,
            'Gender': player.user.gender,
            'Team': 'Something',
        }
        context['data'].append(info)
    return context
```

Comment: Looks like that is a problem, but he updated a question and you can see that exception is `KeyError(): 'Name'`: that is strange. Maybe he lost something critical when he simplified code for question... Also you can see in trace details that context is `{'data': {}}` - it has `'data'` key.. but again it should still fail with `attribute error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'`... I think we'd need more clarifications on what code is really used.

Comment: @imposeren I'm not much sure about the OP. But this will work...won't it? Because I've assigned data as a list.

Comment: Your code should work for sure. I'm just not sure that @Bryson correctly described what his problem really is: maybe something very different is happening there.

Comment: Sorry had to quickly do something, this is the entire code for the my get_context_data

Comment: @Bryson, so is your problem fixed with this answer? If not... are you sure that the problem is in this code and not in the DjangoTemplate? E.g. do you have line `Error during template rendering` after the `Exception Value: 'Name'`?

Comment: @imposeren yes it was fixed with that and a reload of the local django server